# Audio Filters algorithms

Tags: android, algorithm, audio, byte

I would like to add a filter to an audio file (.wav) by modifying bytes, but the problem i have is that sound has a noise.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private int bufferSize = 0;
    private static final int RECORDER_BPP = 16;
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV = ".wav";
    private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "ks";

    private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
    private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
    private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLERATE,
                RECORDER_CHANNELS, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING);

        String file1 = "/storage/emulated/0/File/rec.wav";
        String file2 = "/storage/emulated/0/File/rec2.wav";
        copyWaveFile(file1,file2);
    }

    static final float ALPHA = 0.15f;

    private float[] lowPass(float[] input, float[] output) {
        if (output == null)
            return input;


        for (int n = 0; n < input.length; n++) {
            output[n] = output[n] + ALPHA * (input[n] - output[n]);
        }
        return output;

    }

    private static float[] toFloatArray(byte[] buffer) {
        ByteArrayInputStream bas = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
        DataInputStream ds = new DataInputStream(bas);
        float[] fArr = new float[buffer.length / 4]; // 4 bytes per float
        for (int i = 0; i < fArr.length; i++) {
            try {
                fArr[i] = ds.readFloat();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("E", "eRRO :" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return fArr;
    }

    private static byte[] toByteArray(float[] fArr) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream ds = new DataOutputStream(bas);
        for (float f : fArr)
            try {
                ds.writeFloat(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.i("", "ERROR:" + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        byte[] bytes = bas.toByteArray();

        return bytes;
    }

    private void copyWaveFile(String file1, String file2) {
        FileInputStream in1 = null;
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        long totalAudioLen = 0;
        long totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;
        long longSampleRate = RECORDER_SAMPLERATE;
        int channels = 2;
        long byteRate = RECORDER_BPP * RECORDER_SAMPLERATE * channels / 8;

        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
        byte[] dataOut = new byte[bufferSize];
        float[] floatArray = null;
        try {
            in1 = new FileInputStream(file1);
            out = new FileOutputStream(file2);

            totalAudioLen = in1.getChannel().size();
            totalDataLen = totalAudioLen + 36;

            WriteWaveFileHeader(out, totalAudioLen, totalDataLen,
                    longSampleRate, channels, byteRate);

            while (in1.read(data) != -1) {

                floatArray = lowPass(toFloatArray(data), toFloatArray(dataOut));
                // out.write(data); original 
                out.write(toByteArray(floatArray));
            }

            out.close();
            in1.close();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Done!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void WriteWaveFileHeader(FileOutputStream out, long totalAudioLen,
            long totalDataLen, long longSampleRate, int channels, long byteRate)
            throws IOException {

        byte[] header = new byte[44];

        header[0] = 'R'; // RIFF/WAVE header
        header[1] = 'I';
        header[2] = 'F';
        header[3] = 'F';
        header[4] = (byte) (totalDataLen & 0xff);
        header[5] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[6] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[7] = (byte) ((totalDataLen >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[8] = 'W';
        header[9] = 'A';
        header[10] = 'V';
        header[11] = 'E';
        header[12] = 'f'; // 'fmt ' chunk
        header[13] = 'm';
        header[14] = 't';
        header[15] = ' ';
        header[16] = 16; // 4 bytes: size of 'fmt ' chunk
        header[17] = 0;
        header[18] = 0;
        header[19] = 0;
        header[20] = 1; // format = 1
        header[21] = 0;
        header[22] = (byte) channels;
        header[23] = 0;
        header[24] = (byte) (longSampleRate & 0xff);
        header[25] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[26] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[27] = (byte) ((longSampleRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[28] = (byte) (byteRate & 0xff);
        header[29] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[30] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[31] = (byte) ((byteRate >> 24) & 0xff);
        header[32] = (byte) (2 * 16 / 8); // block align
        header[33] = 0;
        header[34] = RECORDER_BPP; // bits per sample
        header[35] = 0;
        header[36] = 'd';
        header[37] = 'a';
        header[38] = 't';
        header[39] = 'a';
        header[40] = (byte) (totalAudioLen & 0xff);
        header[41] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 8) & 0xff);
        header[42] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 16) & 0xff);
        header[43] = (byte) ((totalAudioLen >> 24) & 0xff);

        out.write(header, 0, 44);
    }
}
```

Someone who can help me with the strange sound and how to get more algorithms of audio filters and implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Matlab to see the type of wave and what kind of frequency the noise exists in. Then you can design the low pass filter to have the cutoff frequency at the boundary of the noise.

Comment: Do you have an example or tutorial ?

Comment: [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html).           The link provides the matlab function to implement Fast Fourier Transform. Basically fft will transform waveform from time domain into frequency domain. You can observe the output waveform magnitude with regard to frequency. From there you can determine where the main frequency component of signal and noise are and can make the decision on how to implement the filter. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to build a Infinite Impulse Response (IIR) filter (I guess you are from the code), the filter equation will be a weighted sum of the current input sample and previous output sample(s).

Your noise may well come about because of `output[n]` has not yet been calculated on the right hand side of the equation.

As for designing filters, I hope your maths is good - you will need to work through this from first principles to understand how it works.  Many people use MatLab to actually calculate the coefficients once they've decided on a filter type and order.

As for tutorials - look at around free university courseware - this is first and second year undergraduate material on electronic engineering degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, a WAV file doesn't contain floats, it contains integers. By decoding them as floats you're getting a totally inappropriate signal - I'm surprised you can hear anything in the output at all.

Second, your `lowPass` function doesn't do a low pass filter. Even if it did, you'd need to check for overflow/underflow and clamp the values back into a valid range.

Comment: Oh thanks but what kind of format it's better to add filter?,Do you know any kind of algorithms?